# Couldn't get Console instance when trying to run a jar from java

Tags: java, executable-jar

When running the following code which executes a jar and exits successfully, but the jar doesn't work and I get the output "Couldn't get Console instance when trying to run a jar from java"

```
       final Runtime re = Runtime.getRuntime();

        final Process command = re.exec("java -jar C:\\dev\\azure-workbench-client\\src\\test\\resources\\azure-file-upload-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar "+
        "C:\\dev\\azure-workbench-client\\src\\test\\resources\\settings.properties C:\\dev\\azure-workbench-client\\src\\test\\resources\\dummyfile");
        this.error = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(command.getErrorStream()));
        this.op = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(command.getInputStream()));
        // Wait for the application to Finish
        command.waitFor();
        this.exitVal = command.exitValue();
        if (this.exitVal != 0) {
            throw new IOException("Failed to execure jar, " + this.getExecutionLog());
        }
        System.out.println("** " + this.getExecutionLog());
```

Any idea what's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the jar I was executing was trying to use the console to receive input.

I removed this and it works.